# What is meant by 'intestinal fortitude'? 'ovariological fortitude'?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is a good example of 'intestinal fortitude' when someone faces his/her fair share of adversity and bounces back from it? Or when a boxer is repeatedly pummeled and knocked down in a fight, and he keeps returning to his feet to continue notwithstanding the beating endured (he's showing a lot of heart, internal strength and 'guts')? Can you say 'He had the intestinal fortitude ('guts') to call me a buffoon'? Is 'ovariological fortitude' the female equivalent of this term?

Answer (score 1):

*Intestinal fortitude* is merely a mock-sophisticated synonym for *guts* meaning “tenacious strength or courage,” popular among sports commentators. You can use the two terms interchangeably, although *intestinal fortitude* may come across as affected or pretentious.

*Guts* isn't a gendered term, so I'm not sure why you'd want a feminine version of it, and I would not expect people to infer *guts* from your proposed alternative.

Comment: Does it aptly fit my examples?

Comment: As I said, it will probably sound affected unless you're a sportscaster.